# Reference that simple $L^2$ stochastic processes are dense in the set of predictable $L^2$ processes

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $W=\{W_t\}_{t\in[0;T]}$ be a Brownian motion, $\{F_t\}_{t\in [0;T]}$ the filtration generated by $W$, augmented with the nullsets. Let $\{X_t\}_{t\in[0;T]}$ be a read-valued, predictable and square-integrable stochastic process.

In my lecture notes, I read that then there exists a sequence $\{X^n_t\}_{t\in[0;T]}$ of stochastic processes where
$$
 X^n_t
 =
 \sum_{i=0}^{K^n-1} Y^{n,i} \cdot \textbf 1_{(t^{n,i};t^{n,i+1}]}(t)
$$
for some $K^n$, $0 = t^{n,0} < t^{n,1} < \ldots < t^{n,K^n} = T$ and $Y^{n,i} \in \mathcal L^2(\Omega,\mathcal F_{t^{n,i}},\mathbb P;\mathbb R)$ such that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb E\bigg(\int_0^T (X_t - X^n_t)^2 \mathrm dt\bigg) = 0.
$$

I am looking for a proper reference to this theorem. Multiple references are also welcome. Thank you!

Comment: you can check the Lemma 4.3.3 of "Introduction to stochastic integration" by H.H. Kuo